# Entity Framework Fluent API to map simple one-to-many relation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I’ve got two tables:

- Documents(Id, DocumentTypeId, Title, Details)
- DocumentTypes (Id, Name, Description).

DocumentTypeId is a foreign key that refers to DocumentTypes table. I.e. all documents can should
   have a type assigned to them.

I’ve got two classes:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class DocumentType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and I’ve got a configuration

```
internal class DocumentsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>
{
    public DocumentsConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Documents");
        HasKey(document => document.Id);
        Property(document => document.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        HasRequired(document => document.DocumentType);//????????

        Property(document => document.Title).HasColumnName("Title").IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And this is not working. I’m getting this error message:

```
Invalid column name 'DocumentType_Id'
```

If I rename the fk column to be DocumentType_Id then I’m getting this error message:

```
Invalid column name 'DocumentTypeId'
```

My question is how do I set such one-to-many relation? I.e. I’d like to have many documents with different document types.

Comment: I wrote an article on how navigation properties work which may be useful to you http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/07/entity-framework-navigation-property.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make this change.  Navigation properties have to be `virtual`:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your configuration to this:

```
internal class DocumentsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Document>
{
    public DocumentsConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(document => document.DocumentType)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(e => e.MapKey("DocumentTypeId"));
        Property(document => document.Title).HasColumnName("Title").IsRequired();
        ToTable("Documents");
    }
}
```

You don't need the `HasKey` or `Property` calls for the `Id` field because they are already assumed by convention.  Your table must have a column `DocumentId` in this configuration.

Comment: virtual is only required for lazy loading (which i personally am not a great fan of) I feel it is much better to be explicit about what you get from the database. This avoids a whole bunch of performance issues.

Comment: im not disagreeing, just wanted to point out that it isn't required and perhaps shouldn't be used :)

Comment: Didn't get this. Sorry for being slow. Did you mean DocumentTypeId instead of DocumentId? As I have a DocumentTypeId FK in Documents table, and DocumentTypes doesn't know anything about Documents table at all...

Comment: @BashirMagomedov Yes, that was a typo. My answer is edited - should have been `"DocumentTypeId"`.

Comment: Thanks. Playing with it... it's not picking it up. Although there are no exceptions anymore, but DocumentType property for all loaded documents are null instead :( Checking...

Comment: @Yuck unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me :( DocumentType is always null - but I've got several document types defined in the database :(

Comment: @Yuck Ok I was wrong :) it is working! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It works only when I make DocumentType property virtual and returns null otherwise. Do you know why?

Comment: @BashirMagomedov You have to call `Include` if you're not using lazy loading.

Comment: Yep... got it -- Eager loading... reading about it now. Thanks! :)