# Entity Framework One-to-Many with Default

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I'm trying to do a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework where one of the many items is optionally designated as default.

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Item DefaultItem { get; set; }          // Optional
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public SomeEntity SomeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration for the one-to-many in fluent API seems pretty straightforward:

```
HasMany(e => e.Items).WithRequired(i => i.SomeEntity).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But the solution for implementing the default item has proven elusive.  I tried this (and various variations) with no luck.  It tells me that 'Schema specified is not valid'.

```
HasOptional(e => e.DefaultItem).WithRequired(i => i.SomeEntity);
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458887/entity-framework-fluent-api-to-map-simple-one-to-many-relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bit untypical 'setup' (and it's usually designated via some 'flag' on the item - but I can possibly see a need for something similar), and relating one item to the same parent twice.

However, this should work...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.DefaultItem)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal() // x => x.DefaultForEntity)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
...
// public SomeEntity DefaultForEntity { get; set; } // optional
```

...and use it like:

```
var item = new Item { ItemName = "Default1", };
db.SomeEntities.Add(new SomeEntity { DefaultItem = item, Items = new[]
{
    item,
    new Item{ ItemName = "Item1", },
    new Item{ ItemName = "Item2", },
    new Item{ ItemName = "Item3", },
    new Item{ ItemName = "Item4", },
}
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks so much!  The reason I didn't use a flag is because that would allow the possibility of two records have their flags set.  Having a single field that holds the Id of the default item ensures that there is no possibility of any errors in the data.