# entity framework multiple relationships

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm new to Entity Framework and I have probably a simple question.

I have simplified the structure at a maximum to be clear (I hope I am).

Imagine that I just need to create a simple "Enterprise" class, with only a Name.
Then another class named "Worker" with also just a Name for the worker.
A worker should belong to an Enterprise.
An Enterprise must have a manager (who is a Worker).

So here is how I imagine these simple classes :

```
public class Worker
{
    public int WorkerId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public int EnterpriseId { get; set; } // ForeignKey for Enterprise
    public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
}

public class Enterprise
{
    public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Worker Manager { get; set; }
    public List<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like these classes to result in the following DB structure :

```
Table Worker
    WorkerId (PK, int, not null)
    Name (varchar(128), not null)
    EnterpriseId (FK, int)

Table Enterprise
    EnterpriseId (PK, int, not null)
    Name (varchar(128), not null)
    Manager (FK, int)
```

I tried many things with modelBuilder, but I never obtain what I want.
Is there a solution with Fluent API to do what I want to do?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not get you what you want (in Db) - **but is what I recommend**...

```
public ICollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; } // instead of List<>
// ...
modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Enterprise)
    .WithMany(x => x.Workers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.EnterpriseId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Manager)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal() // x => x.DefaultForEntity)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

You can use it like:

```
var enterprise = new Enterprise { Manager = new Worker { Name = "Manager", }, };
enterprise.Workers = new[]
{
    enterprise.Manager,
    new Worker{ Name = "Worker1", },
    new Worker{ Name = "Worker2", },
    new Worker{ Name = "Worker3", },
    new Worker{ Name = "Worker4", },
    new Worker{ Name = "Worker5", },
};
db.Enterprises.Add(enterprise);
db.SaveChanges();
var enterprises = db.Enterprises.ToList();
```

**This is exactly what you want**...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Enterprise)
    .WithMany(x => x.Workers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.EnterpriseId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>()
    .HasKey(x => x.EnterpriseId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Manager)
    .WithOptionalDependent() // x => x.DefaultForEntity)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

...**but will not work** - due to cyclical references (EF error).

Here is a pretty detailed example for a similar / identical solution...

[Entity Framework One-to-Many with Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751798/entity-framework-one-to-many-with-default/15754234#15754234)

Comment: I love this site :)

Thank you both for your answers. They are both interesting.
I'll study them now, and come back to comment quickly.

Comment: That's perfect. It allows me to understand perfectly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you intend to get the manager object, but my guess is you need to use `Inheritance` to make your design optimal. Try this:

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int EmployeeId{ get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Enterprise"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EnterpriseId { get; set; } // ForeignKey for Enterprise

    public Enterprise Enterprise { get; set; }
}

[Table("Workers")] // Table per Type (TPT), This will be your Table name in your database
public class Worker : Employee
{
   //Add properties only related to workers
}

[Table("Managers")] // Table per Type (TPT). This will be your Table name in your database
public class Manager : Employee
{
   //Add properties only related to Managers
}

public class Enterprise
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }
   public String Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: Sorry this is done using `Property Mapping`

**Link**: [Here is a link to simple Fluent Mapping example](http://agilenet.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/entity-framework-code-first-specify-foreign-key-name-in-one-to-many-relationship-with-fluent-api/)

**Link** : [Read about Table per Type (TPT) Inheritance here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)