# Entity Framework 6 One To Many With Additional Navigation Property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to map a class where i have a list of related items and a selected related item.  Basically, I have a workflow with a collection of tasks, and at any given time one of those tasks is the selected as the current task.

```
public class Flow
{
    public int FlowId { get; set; }
    public int CurrentFlowTaskId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual FlowTask CurrentFlowTask { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FlowTask> FlowTasks { get; set; }
}

public class FlowTask
{
    public int FlowTaskId { get; set; }
    public int FlowId { get; set; }
    public string Discription { get; set; }
    public virtual Flow Flow { get; set; }
}
```

And my mapping looks like this:

```
public class FlowMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Flow>
{
    public FlowMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FlowId);
        Property(x => x.IsActive).IsRequired();

        HasOptional(x => x.CurrentFlowTask)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(x => x.FlowTasks)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Flow)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FlowId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class FlowTaskMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FlowTask>
{
    public FlowTaskMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FlowTaskId);
        Property(x => x.Discription).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

This creates a migration that looks like this:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Flows",
    c => new
        {
            FlowId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            CurrentFlowTaskId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            IsActive = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.FlowId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.FlowTasks",
    c => new
        {
            FlowTaskId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            FlowId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Discription = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 25),
            Flow_FlowId = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.FlowTaskId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Flows", t => t.Flow_FlowId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Flows", t => t.FlowId)
    .Index(t => t.FlowId)
    .Index(t => t.Flow_FlowId);
```

The first thing that seems amiss here is the `Flow_FlowId` column that is created in the flow tasks.

When I run the following block of code in LinqPad I do not see the results I expect;  A `Flow` and a `FlowTask` are created, but `Flow.CurrentTaskId` is null, and the off `Flow_FlowId` column is set to the same value as `Flow.FlowId`

```
var fi = new CompWalk.Data.FlowTask
{
    Discription = "Task 1",
};
var f = new CompWalk.Data.Flow {
    IsActive = true,
    CurrentFlowTask = fi,
    FlowTasks = new[] {
        fi
    }
};

Flows.Add(f);
SaveChanges();
```

This code was adapted from an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751798/entity-framework-one-to-many-with-default), but is several years old so may no longer be applicable.

Is what I am attempting possible without doing a multiple inserts and saves?
Also, what is causing the generation of the `Flow_FlowId` column?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different relationship types between `Flow` and `FlowTask`. You configured one-to-many relationship by adding `FlowId` to `FlowTask` and configured it so we have this line in migration

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Flows", t => t.FlowId)
```

which is correct. And there is one-to-one relationship where you marked `Flow` as principal and therefore `FlowTask` is dependent. Entity Framework adds principal Id as foreign key to dependent entity to create such relationship. It's not possible to configure foreign key for one-to-one relationship with entity's property (like you did for one-to-many) in Entity Framework. And because of it framework generates foreign key for you and adds it to dependent entity (`FlowTask`).

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Flows", t => t.Flow_FlowId)
```

And your `public int CurrentFlowTaskId { get; set; }` property is just a regular column and not a foreign key so indeed it's not set in your example. And `Flow_FlowId` is set  to `Flow.FlowId` because it **is** foreign key.

If you want the one-to-one relationship foreign key be added to `Flow` just change this line

```
HasOptional(x => x.CurrentFlowTask)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

to

```
HasOptional(x => x.CurrentFlowTask)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

If you want to specify name of the key change it to following

```
HasOptional(x => x.CurrentFlowTask)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("KeyName"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

But if you decide to add `KeyName` property to `Flow` entity, migration will yield an exception:

```
KeyName: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'KeyName' is already defined.
```

So you won't be able to access this value directly in code and I don't know how fix this. Haven't researched it yet. But I think it should be possible to configure this relationship as one-to-many and use it as one-to-one somehow but I'm not sure.